# Remove all lines after "/"

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have 2 lists one with this format:

```
http://www.example.com/archives/573
http://www.example.com/1812.html
http://example.com/hello-world/
```

but i want it in this format:

```
www.example.com
www.example.com
example.com
```

an the other list in this format:

```
4|345|example.com|themes/vip|Automattic|Nginx 5|425|example.com|themes/informer|Softlayer|Nginx 6|502|example.com|themes/ljq|Media Temple|Apache
```

but i need it in the same format:

```
example.com 
example.com 
example.com
```

please help me.
thank you.

Comment: can you post some code with what you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first case, replace

```
https?://([^/]+)/.*
```

with `\1`.

For the second one, replace

```
\d+\|\d+\|([^|]+)\|.*
```

with `\1`.